# ews java api create contact throws exception: Local name cannot be null

Tags: java, api, office365

I am trying to use ews java api to create a contact. I try to authenticate the service by using the accessToken I have obtained through the OAuth2 workflow. I get an exception `Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: Local name cannot be null`

Here is my code based on the example by github.

```
String accessToken =null;
    Token token = null;
    try
    {
        token = DatabaseUtils.getaccessTokensAPI(uniqueApiID);
        accessToken=token.getAccessToken();

        ExchangeService service  =  new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP2);
        TokenCredentials credentials = new TokenCredentials(accessToken);
        service.setCredentials(credentials);
        service.setUrl(new URI("APP ID URI"));

        Contact contact = new Contact(service);
        contact.setGivenName("ContactName");
        contact.setMiddleName ("mName");
        contact.setSurname("sName");
        contact.setSubject("Contact Details");

        // Specify the company name.
        contact.setCompanyName("technolgies");
        PhysicalAddressEntry paEntry1 = new PhysicalAddressEntry();
        paEntry1.setStreet("12345 Main Street");
        paEntry1.setCity("Seattle");
        paEntry1.setState("orissa");
        paEntry1.setPostalCode("11111");
        paEntry1.setCountryOrRegion("INDIA");
        contact.getPhysicalAddresses().setPhysicalAddress(PhysicalAddressKey.Home, paEntry1);
        contact.save();

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I am not sure if I can use only access token to authenticate service and not sure what to use as parameter service.setUrl() Is App ID URI appropriate?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Post the stack trace, so we can see which bit of your code causes the exception.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of `ExchangeService.SetUrl` is to set the URL of the EWS endpoint, not to set your app id. Assuming this is Office 365, you should set it to https://outlook.office365.com/ews/exchange.asmx

Comment: Thank you Jason Johnston for your reply. I changed the url according to your suggestion but I still get the same exception.